# Do I have to make mysql table relationship with Relation view?

Tags: mysql

I am really confused. DO I have to use "Relation view" and make foreign key relationship  with other table? Or I can do the same thing manually? I mean maintaining relationships without exclusively defining relationship from Relation view?

Thanks..

Comment: You might find some useful info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html